# About the Media Gallery Module

Tags: 7, media

Right now in each gallery, when a user clicks on the thumbnail, a larger version will show up in the middle of the screen. With it are arrows to navigate, a "1 of x" caption, a link to start a slideshow, and an x to close it. When I click the image, it takes me to the page of the media. What I want it to do is take me to the next image in the slideshow (like the arrows would have done). I tried looking at the configuration of the Media Gallery Module but there were only options on column and row layout. When I tried to check the settings in the gallery content type, all of the fields were locked and could not be edited. I tried Google for a solution, but not really anything turned up for this specific problem.

Comment: I see that the [module](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) is in beta version, and what you are asking is more of a feature request rather than question. Similar thread is running on [Issues for media gallery](http://drupal.org/node/1088738).

Answer (score 2):

You should use Firebug and take a look at the function that gets called, when clicking on the "Next"-Button.(Something like onClick() )

Now take a look at the function, that gets called, when you click on the image.

Now just place the "Next"-Button function into the image. Delete the old one.

The functions are usually in a .js-File.

This is not so hard, i am a beginner and managed it with the shadowbox.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this JQuery script to achive your required result. You can use JS Injector Module to insert this script or simply upload a js file in your theme folder and call it through .info file

```
/*
Redirects lightbox image click to advance to next image instead of opening image details.
Via http://drupal.org/node/1088738#comment-4362570
code from #12
Posted by stephandale on April 10, 2011 at 12:26pm
*/
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.initColorboxDefaultStyle = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function () {
    $('.lightbox-stack .gallery-thumb-inner a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.colorbox.next();
      });
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you may see it working on http://go2georgia.travel/

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, and I can tell a little more about the reasons, in an example:

On the Gallery ( /galleries/myGallery) , you click on a photo and the colorbox opens. But the content of the colorbox is not only the image, but the body of /media-gallery/lightbox/11/22 . And this content features a link around the image, namely /media-gallery/detail/11/22 .

I cannot find a way to remove that link, but maybe this helps somebody to remove the problem without overwriting the standard behaviour with JavaScript. Which works of course, but there should be a better way.